# Detect parameters in a ROBLOX player's message? (LUA)

Tags: variables, parameters, lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a simple 'kill command' in Roblox Studio where you type ";kill player" and it will kill them.

The part I am struggling with is how on earth to separate the words before and after the space, and store them as variables?

Steps I need in my code:

1. Check if the message deliverer's **name is equal to the value of 'Owner'**
2. Check if the message **contains ';' at the beginning** (the prefix)
3. Check if the message **contains one space**
4. If all of the above are true, Then set the word *before* the space to the variable,'cmd' and set the word *after* the space to the variable, 'username'.

The rest I can figure out on my own.

Here's what my code is currently:

```lua
local Owner = "Djraco"
local Prefix = ";"


game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.Chatted:Connect(function(msg)
        
         --<code goes here>

    end)

end)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lua
local Owner = "Djraco"
local Prefix = ";"


game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.Chatted:Connect(function(msg)
        
         local msg = msg:split(" ")  -- Seperate your message every space
         if player.Name == Owner and msg[1] == "kill" and msg[2] ~= nil then game:GetService("Players")[msg[2]].Character.Humanoid.Health = 0 end
         

    end)

end)
```

The above should work. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I did have to edit it a bit, on line 9, I had to change `local msg` to `local message` for it to work and rather than just `"kill"` I did `Prefix.."kill"`

But other than that, it seems to be working! thanks much!

Comment: @Datonebassdude right my bad. Rushed the answer but glad that it eventually worked out :)